# Can't figure out how to properly execute exe with arguments

Tags: powershell, arguments

So I have been trying to write a script where I run an executable with arguments  to return some information I need for our monitoring. Not long ago I have written a script that successfully managed to do that, using the following command:

```
$command = "-t vtl -p {1} -m {0} -s"
$check = Invoke-Expression -command ("$exemap\$exe $command" -f $server,$poort)
```

This worked perfectly. However I am in the process of writing a new script and the exact same thing does not seem to be working anymore. Here is a script I have to reproduce the problem:

```
$omgeving = "A"
$exemap = "\\cfc01.corp\rpa-{0}\Scripts\Check_actualiteit_RPA" -f $omgeving
#$exe = "echoargs.exe"
$exe = "stmmon.exe"
$exepath = "$exemap\"+"$exe"
$commando = "-t {0} -p {1} -m {2} -s"
$poort = "5062"
$berichttype = "VTL"
$server = "rpa-a-ap001"
$command = ($commando -f $berichttype,$poort,$server) -split " "
#$command = "-t VTL -p 5062 -m rpa-a-ap001 -s" 

& $exepath $command
```

So I have negated some lines that are there for troubleshooting. I have tried using the `Invoke-Expression` command above and using the `&` operator. I have googled and tried a lot. I have tried using jobs and `Invoke-Command`. But all of them have the same result, an explanation from the exe telling me how to use it:

```
Usage: \\cfc01.corp\rpa-A\Scripts\Check_actualiteit_RPA\stmmon.exe [-v] [-h] -t <type> -p <port> -m <machine> -k <key> [-s]
```

This makes me believe that the executable is not really acknowleding any arguments. I tried using echoargs and the output from the script above is:

```
Arg 0 is <-t>
Arg 1 is <VTL>
Arg 2 is <-p>
Arg 3 is <5062>
Arg 4 is <-m>
Arg 5 is <rpa-a-ap001>
Arg 6 is <-s>
```

Or, if I dont use the -split " " in the $command variable, the echoargs is this:

```
Arg 0 is <-t VTL -p 5062 -m rpa-a-ap001 -s>
```

The script above may not be very dynamic, but the actual script im trying to make is going to be. The argumentlist should be configurable and dynamic, which is why im using the `-f` command on different occasions.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here and why the executable won't even acknowledge the existence of arguments?

Comment: Small note: some programs have really weird ways of parsing commandline arguments. For example, while it seems logical to pass `-t` and `VTL` as separate arguments, the program may want to see them combined as `-t VTL`. Eg.: `Arg 0 is <-t VTL>`.

Comment: Tried to use that format for the arguments, however it did not work. See my echoargs output below:
Arg 0 is <-t VTL>
Arg 1 is <-p 5062>
Arg 2 is <-m rpa-a-ap001>
Arg 3 is <-s>

Answer (score 0):

Use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`) for running external commands. Use [`Join-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) for building paths. Use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) for passing arguments to a program or function.

```
$omgeving = "A"
$exemap   = "\\cfc01.corp\rpa-$omgeving\Scripts\Check_actualiteit_RPA" -f 
$exe      = "stmmon.exe"

$exepath  = Join-Path $exemap $exe

$params = '-t', 'VTL',
          '-p', 5062,
          '-m', 'rpa-a-ap001',
          '-s'

& $exepath @params
```

Also, judging from the help output, you seem to be missing a required parameter:

```
Usage: \\...\stmmon.exe [-v] [-h] -t <type> -p <port> -m <machine> -k <key> [-s]
```

If everything else fails, try this as a workaround:

```
$type   = 'VTL'
$port   = 5062
$server = 'rpa-a-ap001'

& cmd /c ('"{0}" -t {1} -p {2} -m {3} -s' -f $exepath, $type, $port, $server)
```

Comment: This is the first time I heard about splatting, and it seems to be very useful! Thanks a lot for this tip. However, I have just tried your suggestion and it is not changing anything. I have used the join-path and tried your $params etc. The other scripts that are using this executable never use the -k argument. I will see if it helps to fill it in.

Comment: P.s. if I type `& .\stmmon.exe -t vtl -p 5062 -m rpa-a-ap001 -s` in powershell, I get the desired output.

Comment: If that works I would expect a the command to work with splatted parameters as well, but see my updated answer, just for good measure.

Comment: I am sorry, but not even that is working :(. I am beginning to think there may be some kind of bug. It is especially weird that other scripts are not having this issue while I have tried the same way to use the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to have wasted people's time here.
I have discovered the problem here. Apparently the 'type' arguments does not allow capital letters. I had not yet tried to change those, but it seems to have fixed the issue.